# What is the difference in creating an instance of a class inside a thread loop versus outside

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have recently started working on threads and queues in Python. I have seen the following pattern for multi threading and queuing:

```
VALID_TARGETS = ['10.192.20.2','10.233.1.3', '10,235,0.3']

queue2 = Queue.Queue(maxsize=10)
for target in VALID_TARGETS:
    queue2.put(target)
for i in range(100):
    try:
        valAuth_obj = ValAuth(queue2, user_id, pwd)
        valAuth_obj.daemon = True
        valAuth_obj.start()
    except Exception, error:
        print "ERROR"
        break
queue2.join()
```

Where `ValAuth` is a class inheriting `threading.Threads`, whose `run` function is:

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        target = self.queue.get()
        self.login(target)
        self.queue.task_done()
```

The program is running as expected. But i have noticed we are calling the class `valAuth` for every thread i want to run. Then i tried the following, where i pulled out the `valAuth()` outside the loop.

```
VALID_TARGETS = ['10.192.20.2','10.233.1.3', '10,235,0.3']

queue2 = Queue.Queue(maxsize=10)
valAuth_obj = ValAuth(queue2, user_id, pwd)

for target in VALID_TARGETS:
    queue2.put(target)

for i in range(100):
    try:
        valAuth_obj.daemon = True
        valAuth_obj.start()
    except Exception, error:
        print "ERROR"
        break
queue2.join()
```

The program still gives me the same result but I can notice there is some difference in terms of speed. Can someone please explain what is the difference in terms of background operations and which one should we stick to?

CODE for valAuth class

```
class valAuth(threading.Thread):
    """ Authenticate all targeted SCM build machines """
    def __init__(self, queue, user_id, password):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.user = user
        self.password = password        

    def run(self):
        while True:
            target = self.queue.get()
            self.auth(target)
            self.queue.task_done()

    def auth(self, target):
        """ Check all SCM build machines are active with login authentication and
            also checks if the account is not AD locked.
        """
        print "P1: " + self.user + " target: "+ target
        # Company's Authentication Protocol base code ... (cannot show ! SORRY !)
        print "P1: " + self.user + " target: "+ target + " Run complete"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you created a `ValAuth.start()` method? The inherited `threading.Thread.start()` method should fail if called multiple times for the same object as it is done in your second variant.

Comment: Do you mean making instances of a class? Your post's title sounds like you mean generating classes in threads

Comment: @MichaelButscher, no i have not written `valAuth.start()`. From what i have understood in the documentation is that calling `valAuth_obj.start()` will trigger the `valAuth.run()` function internally.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, i have ran both variants and found no issues in running them. So i added couple of print statements (P1 and P2) at the start and then end of my `login()`  and found only the order of prints to be different. Lets say i am running 4 threads the print order is "P1 P1 P1 P1 P2 P2 P2 P2", where as for variant2 the print order is "P1 P2 P1 P2 P1 P2 P1 P2". For variant2 i am getting more synchronized prints.  I am not sure why ? but no failures

`def login(target): 
    print "P1"
    #login statements ....
    print "P2"`

Comment: @EdwardMinnix, yes you are right, its about making instances of classes, sorry for the vague and typo fill subject line. I had to fill this question at 3 in the morning from office.

Comment: Could you show more code of `ValAuth`, especially the first line (`class ...`) and the constructor? I'm pretty sure the second variant can't work this way.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, i have edit my post to include the `class valAuth()`

Comment: You use sometimes `ValAuth`, sometimes `valAuth` in the code examples (different upper/lower-case) so these code examples can't work. Have you really tested the examples exactly as given here?

Comment: @MichaelButscher, it is a typo at my end. I have uploaded the script to github, you can pull the script (auth.py) from [authentication](https://github.com/code-fortis/Authentication). (I am running python 2.7)

Comment: I tried it and it creates a lot of `Thread error` messages as expected. When adding a `print error` in the exception handler it shows `cannot set daemon status of active thread` so the `for i in range(6):` loop in `main()` is useless because only in the first iteration a new thread is started, all following iterations fail with an error and do nothing.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, so basically if i have had written a better code on error handling this question would not have been raised. So every time the print statement ran from `def authenticate()` was from the very 1st thread only and the rest of the loop it just ended up running ` valAuth_obj.start()` over and over. Thank you so much for your time on debugging this.

Comment: Right. To be precise it did not even reach `valAuth_obj.start()` in the second iteration and on, `valAuth_obj.daemon = True` failed already for a running thread. A simple helpful exception handling is for instance a call to `traceback.print_exc()`